# How to print a specific line in a csv file that is not named csv in python?

Tags: python

I'm supposed to write a function that does this specifically.

```
def get_customer_record(file_handle, n):
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Find the n-th record in a comma-delimited sequential file.
    Records are numbered starting with 0.
    Use: result = get_customer_record(file_handle, n)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Parameters:
        file_handle - file to search (file - open for reading)
        n - the number of the record to return (int > 0)
    Returns:
        result - a list of the fields of the n-th record if it exists,
            an empty list otherwise (list)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """
```

And here is the file.

**customers.txt**

```
12345,Tom,Black,300.00,1998-01-30
23456,Alice,Smith,1200.50,1998-02-20
14567,Jane,White,900.00,1998-07-01
43564,Weilin,Zhao,450.25,1998-01-03
45432,Bina,Mehta,278.95,1998-03-21
```

The Code

```
list = [] 
file_handle = open('customers.txt', 'r+', encoding="utf-8") 
line = file_handle.readline(n) 
list.append(line.strip(',')) 
file_handle.close() 
return list
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far? In what way is it not working?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Comment: Welcome to SO, we are a community of volunteers that help answer questions/issues in code. Unfortunately I see no code here, we don't write programs. Please try to answer this yourself and come back if you run into any issues. Don't be afraid to search your question/issue before asking

Comment: Maybe it would help to read about python's CSV Module - https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html or perhaps Python's input and output syntax - https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: @Kingsley 
 
    list = []

    file_handle = open('customers.txt', 'r+', encoding="utf-8")

    line = file_handle.readline(n)
    list.append(line.strip(','))
    file_handle.close()
    
    return list
I have tried doing this, here was what I have in my testing file.

from functions import get_customer_record
file_handle = open('customers.txt', 'r+', encoding="utf-8")
n = int(input())

result = get_customer_record(file_handle, n)

print(list)

Comment: @DavidEnjugu it can be a bit tricky to read code in comments. Paste your code into your question by editing it. Also, I'd second the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module

Comment: @C.Nivs 
Alright, thanks

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be iterate through the file using [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

```
from csv import reader

def get_customer_record(file_handle, n):
    with open(file=file_handle) as csvfile:
        csv_reader = reader(csvfile)
        return next((line for row, line in enumerate(csv_reader) if row == n), [])

print(get_customer_record(file_handle='customer.csv', n=3))
# ['43564', 'Weilin', 'Zhao', '450.25', '1998-01-03']

print(get_customer_record(file_handle='customer.csv', n=5))
# []
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your syntax whether to return just the row as a string, or the fields split around the `,`.  I have assumed the single-line.

The python `readline()` function does not take an index, it just reads the *next* line from the file.  Below I used `readlines()` (note the `s`) which reads all lines from the file.  If your file was huge, this would not be so efficient.

Also a bit of error-handling for out-of-bounds `n` helps:

```
def get_customer_record(file_handle, n):
    lines = file_handle.readlines()
    if (n >= 0 and n < len(lines)):
        return lines[n] # or n-1?
    else:
        return None

file_handle = open( 'customers.txt', 'r+', encoding="utf-8" )
fields = get_customer_record( file_handle, 3 )
print( str( fields )  )
```

Of course you may not want to read the whole file, just the next Nth record

```
def get_customer_record(file_handle, n):
    if (n >= 0):
        line = file_handle.readline()
        while (n > 0):
            line = file_handle.readline()
            if (line == ''):
                line = None
                break  # end of file
            n -= 1
        return line
    else:
        return None
```

Obviously this code assumes that `n` is indexed 0 -> (N-1).

Comment: Really appreciate the help, my only question is why did you use 3? in the line 
fields = get.....
Thank you

Comment: @DavidEnjugu I used 3 just as a test number, no particular reason.  But FWIW I tested with 0, 5, 50 and -4 too.